# Need help centering my text

Tags: tables

This is my code:

```
\begin{flushleft}
\begin{center}
\begin{tabular}{|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|}
\hline
$x$&0&$\displaystyle\frac{\pi}{6}$&$\displaystyle\frac{\pi}{4}$&$\displaystyle\frac{\pi}{3}$&$\displaystyle\frac{\pi}{2}$&$\pi$\\ \hline
$\cos(x)$&1&$\displaystyle\frac{\sqrt3}{2}$&$\displaystyle\frac{\sqrt2}{2}$&$\displaystyle\frac{1}{2}$&0&-1\\ \hline
$\sin(x)$&0&$\displaystyle\frac{1}{2}$&$\displaystyle\frac{\sqrt2}{2}$&$\displaystyle\frac{\sqrt3}{2}$&1&0\\ \hline
$\tan(x$)&0&0&1&0&0&0\\ \hline
\end{tabular}
\end{center}
\end{flushleft}
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX-SE! Wy are you using `center` inside `flushleft`?

Comment: Are you sure about `\tan(\pi/6)=\tan(\pi/3)=\tan(\pi/2)=0`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would simplify the table's layout by doing away with all vertical lines and the majority of horizontal lines. Since all the contents are processed in math mode, I would use an `array` environment instead of a `tabular` environment.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{booktabs} % for \toprule, \midrule, \bottomrule, and \addlinespace macros
\begin{document}
\[
\begin{array}{@{} l *{6}{>{\displaystyle}c} @{}}
\toprule
x       & 0 &\frac{\pi}{6}   &\frac{\pi}{4}   &\frac{\pi}{3}   &\frac{\pi}{2}&\pi\\ 
\midrule
\cos(x) & 1 &\frac{\sqrt3}{2}&\frac{\sqrt2}{2}&\frac{1}{2}     &0            &-1 \\ 
\addlinespace
\sin(x) & 0 &\frac{1}{2}     &\frac{\sqrt2}{2}&\frac{\sqrt3}{2}&1            &0  \\ 
\addlinespace
\tan(x) & 0 &\frac{1}{\sqrt3}&1               &\sqrt3          &\infty       &0  \\ 
\bottomrule
\end{array}
\]
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1):

Welcome to TeX-SE! I would just add a table and use `\centering` to center it. Also you can use an `array` instead of switching to math mode in every cell by hand.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{array}
\begin{document}
\begin{table}[htb]
\centering\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{2}
$\begin{array}{|*7{>{\displaystyle\vphantom{\raisebox{2pt}{\Bigg[}}}c|}}
\hline
x&0&\frac{\pi}{6}&\frac{\pi}{4}&\frac{\pi}{3}&\frac{\pi}{2}&\pi\\
\hline
\cos(x)&1&\frac{\sqrt3}{2}&\frac{\sqrt2}{2}&\frac{1}{2}&0&-1\\
\hline
\sin(x)&0&\frac{1}{2}&\frac{\sqrt2}{2}&\frac{\sqrt3}{2}&1&0\\ 
\hline
\tan(x)&0&0&1&0&0&0\\ \hline
\end{array}$
\caption{\dots}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks a lot and ik tan values are not right it was just for the layout haha

Comment: @BesoinClément I just saw you are using Mico's answer. If this is what you prefer, you may consider accepting their post.

Comment: Yeah sure Idk how to do so though haha